# Hiding NavigationDrawer on app start

Tags: android, navigation, hide, drawer

I have problem with my application, I use NavigationDrawer in it, and whenever my app is launching, NavigationDrawer is opened. I have no idea what is causing this, but this is annoying... How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can close the Navigation drawer.

Ex:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aww, found what was causing this problem.
In my main fragment object, nawigation drawer is set by setUp method of "NavigationDrawerFragment" object. In this method there are lines:

```
if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}
```

which are causing problem that I described. As I do not need this navigation drawer to show at first app run, I deleted those lines. That's it.
I guess too much coffe and too little of sleep does not help my perceptiveness, as I was browsing my code and did not figured this out... Anyway, thanks for help.